# How to (caml)query a list on metedata in the MetaInfo field

Tags: caml-query, metadata

Is it possible to write a CAML-query to filter documents with certain info in the `MetaInfo` field? The information is only stored as the property in MetaInfo, not in a field of it's own.

**Context:** I have a document library with loads (100.000) of documents which were migrated there from the other system. The migration tool copied a lot of metadata into the `MetaInfo` field. Some of the documents have 'unwanted' information in this MetaInfo collection.
This can easily be corrected per file (`listItem.properties.delete(key)`) but the hard part is finding the files with the 'bad' information in the `MetaInfo`-field.